# Easiest way to make ToolStripMenuItem.Selected = true

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` named `mailResultsToolStripMenuItem`. Now I want it to be `.Selected = true` when users click on it and `.Selected = false` when users click it again. I tried:

```
mailResultsToolStripMenuItem.Selected = true;
```

but it shows an error that the property is *read-only*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you looking for [`ToolStripMenuItem.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checked.aspx)?

```
// true if the ToolStripMenuItem is checked or is in an indeterminate state;
// otherwise, false. The default is false.
mailResultsToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
// Also interesting: mailResultsToolStripMenuItem.CheckState
//                   mailResultsToolStripMenuItem.CheckOnClick
```